# Using Swup with Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, href, swup

**My Issue**:

I am trying to use Swup Library with Django's templating engine and everything worked well; **except for the fetching of new content.**

The animations worked perfectly; I could see my contents getting faded out.
The addresses in which the get requests are fetching worked perfectly as well; I could see the HTTP response code of 200 being returned in my console.
However, the main content, after being faded out, were not being replaced.

---

An example of Django Renderings:
Base URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000

```html
<!-- What is written in my code -->
<a href="{% url 'home_view' %}" >
<!-- What Django renders in the browser -->
<a href="/" >
```

in my urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homeView, name='home_view'),
]
```

A worthy note: Using dev tools, when hovering over the href rendered, it shows http://127.0.0.1:8000/

---

Another strange thing I encountered when trying to debug was that my html element has the following attributes added to it but it stay there even after the animation ends.

```html
<html lang="en" class="swup-enabled is-changing is-leaving is-animating to-homepage">
```

---

**Swup config or any additional relevant code used**:

```js
let options = {
    LINK_SELECTOR: 'a',
    debugMode: true,
};
const swup = new Swup(options);
```

The Scripts loaded perfectly; I was able to see them in my developer tools, under the Sources tab.

```
<head>
  <script defer src="{% static 'swup.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script defer src="{% static 'script.js' %}"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"/>
</head>
```

---

**Before creating this issue, I did the following:**:

- [x] Checked closed issues for similar/related problems.
- [x] Changing LINK_SELECTOR as stated in the docs.
- [x] Changing the href to using '/' at the start so that it will get picked up.

---

I have tried and exhausted all possible means of solutions found googling around and in stack overflow as well.
Please do point me to a more appropriate resource if there are any suggestions!
Thank you if you have read this far!